# Где хранятся результаты вызова функции с замыканием и захватом значений в Swift?

Tags: swift, функции

Есть такая функция с замыканием и захватом значения

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
     var runningTotal = 0
     func incrementer() -> Int {
          runningTotal += amount
          return runningTotal
     }
     return incrementer
}


let incrementByTen = makeIncrement(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen()
// возвращает 10
incrementByTen()
// возвращает 20
incrementByTen()
// возвращает 30
```

Затем передаем второй аргумент и сохраняем результат в новой константе

```
let incrementBySeven = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 7)

incrementBySeven()
// Возвращает 7
incrementBySeven()
// Возвращает 14
```

Теперь снова используем предыдущую константу / функцию и с аргументом 10

```
incrementByTen()
// возвращает 40
```

Т.е. получается, что функция хранит результаты предыдущих вызовов наряду с последующими.

Где хранятся результаты таких вызовов?

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Если отвечать на него прямо то будет примерно так: результаты хранятся в лексическом окружении вашего замыкания. В данном случае в него входит ваша переменная `runningTotal`. Для каждого нового замыкания создаётся своя копия окружения (происходит т.н. "захват окружения"), поэтому вы наблюдаете такое поведение, где каждая возвращенная функция совершенно независима, несмотря на то что вроде бы используется одна и та же общая переменная.

По "определению" замыкание это сочетание функции и её лексического окружения.

На MDN есть [хорошая статья про замыкания](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), и хотя она описывает замыкания JavaScript общие принципы должны быть актуальны для любого языка.

Comment: спасибо огромное, отличный ответ! В двух словах основное! И статья тоже очень полезная.  Один уточняющий вопрос - правильно я понимаю, что захват в данном случае скорее подразумевает захват как удержание значения переменной вложенной функцией внутри себя? И что при следующем вызове этого экземпляра вложенной функции она уже не пользуется значением переменной из внешней основной функции, а берет свое значение, захваченное и удерживаемое внутри себя?

Comment: @maxMas в целом верно. В принципе контекст и функцию замыкания легко представлять как класс где функция это метод класса, захваченные переменные - члены класса, а само замыкание это экземпляр класса.

Comment: да, это действительно напоминает объект с его свойствами и методами. И еще, можно ли говорить, что лексическое окружение хранится в создаваемой константе, которой приписывается ссылка на функцию. Ведь весь остальной путь одинаков и разница есть только по этим константам.

Comment: @maxMas нет, аналогия с классом хороша для понимания, но всё же не соответствует фактической взаимосвязи. Лексический контекст это отдельный объект на который у функции есть ссылка. Т.о. на один и тот же контекст могут ссылатся несколько функций.  Кроме того лексические контексты связаны цепочкой "наследования" - у каждого контекста есть ссылка на родительский контекст, которая в общем-то и обеспечивает всю "магию" захвата контекста. На англоязычном SO есть хороший ответ на этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491626/where-does-a-javascript-closure-live

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что в данном случае, при захвате функцией значений, они копируются в нее и далее функция работает уже со своей скопированной переменной.

Подробный разбор данного примера есть вот тут:
http://swiftbook.ru/doc/closures/capturing-values